# Catch SqlException at the controller level?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

In my WebApi 2 project I follow service pattern as well as unit of work and generic repository patterns.

All controllers have `try-catch`, and just in case an action doesn't I have a global `IAutofacExceptionFilter` will catches unhandled exceptions.

The service layer also has exception handling. However, the repository don't have exception handling so that the exception bubble up to this first `try-catch` they encounter.

I also have a custom `DatabaseException` class that captures EF's database exceptions thrown on `SaveChanges` and this works fine.

However, as the project is currently under heavy development with database changes occurring at the same same as code changes, exceptions such `SQLException` or `EntityCommandExecutionException` are quite common. I would like to catch these kind of exceptions and throw my own `DatabaseException`.

Should I catch these exceptions at the repository level, the service level or the controller level?

Comment: Rethrow as close to it's origin as possible. This way you'll still be able to differentiate if you want to.

Comment: My suggestion is to log the exception in controller level and throw an exception with a generic message from controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question - I would catch exceptions at the service level, log them, and then re-throw them.

- Retrieving data from the database is a function of the service, so if that's failing, it's the service that's failing.
- The application doesn't "know" about the database. It doesn't get data from the database. It gets data from the service. It shouldn't depend on implementation details in the service like whether the data comes from SQL or somewhere else.

Now that the exception is rethrown, the application can also handle it, even logging it again - this time in the context of what controller action was called. But if, for example, the user is trying to save some data and it fails, it probably doesn't matter too much in that context why it failed. So it probably isn't that helpful to catch specific exception types. (Probably.)

Catching specific types of exceptions is only really helpful if the application is going to take some different action to handle or resolve the exception, which is uncommon. Being able to easily get to your logs and find an exception, any exception, will be way more valuable than converting a system exception to a custom exception.

Comment: Errors that occur on the context will get propagated up to your BAL or Model where you call _context.<some entity or action>. If these functions are wrapped in try-catch you will catch the exception. When you initialize the context in a using statement it will catch your connection specific errors.

Comment: I meant "context" in more vague sense - an exception thrown while handling a request in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I don't have try_catchs in my MVC applications (excluding one or two existing try catchs)

All my controllers are inherited from `BaseController`
where I've an attribute that catch's all the exceptions in my application:

```
public class HandleExceptionsAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Exception.InsertIntoDB(Membership.CurrentUserId, filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString());
    }
}

[HandleExceptionsAttribute(View = "/Error/Index")]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    // Code...
}
```

In `HandleErrorAttribute` you may even choose which page you want to show if an error occurs.

If you want to filter a specific exception:

```
if (filterContext.Exception is EntityCommandExecutionException)
                // code
```

**NOTE**

To see in which action and controller the exception occurs, I get the current controller and the current action and insert it to the database.